# Split method in python is outputing an index error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program takes in a txt file and prints out the first word of each line. It works perfectly but at the end it prints out this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vipku/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(f.readline().split()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code that I wrote

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    for first in line:
        print(f.readline().split()[0])
```

Comment: one of your lines must be empty

Comment: split produces a list, which should be empty if there was nothing there to start with. The error isn't coming from split; it's coming from [0]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the line is empty before getting the first element:

```py
f = open("example.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.strip():
        print(line.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    for first in line:
```

actually means:

```
open file "example.txt" for reading
for every line in that file:
    for every character in that line:
```

So this means you do `readline` more times that actual number of lines - due to this you get empty `str` from `readline`, as [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) says *if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by '\n', a string containing only a single newline.*

It is enough to use single `for` if you want to deal with line after line. You should check for blank lines (lines consisting of single newline - using `.split` at them result in empty list), so solution might looks like:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    if words:
        print(words[0])
f.close()
```

I harness fact that empty lists are False-y and non-empty list True-y, so print will be executed only if `words` has at least 1 element. Note that files should be closed after usage. You might do it implicitly or use `with open`... approach instead. You might learn about latter from [this realpython tutorial](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/#pythons-with-open-as-pattern).